# Need to move TempDB to another drive. But its files cannot be dropped or shrunk

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, shrink

Today I had a task to move all `TempDB` files to a new, smaller drive (`RAMdisk`). 
I analysed `TempDB`
files space usage - not all the space inside of its files was used so I decided that new drive is ok.
So I had to shrink all the 8 files to make them small enough. I tried to do it with:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'<logicalname>' , <size>)
GO
```

But it took a lot of time and eventually it didn't/almost didn't shrink files.

If I tried to empty a file :

```
USE [tempdb];
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'<logicalname>', EMPTYFILE);
GO
```

it still failed with a message:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE: Page <pageNo> could not be moved because it is a work table page.
```

Then I found some posts about clearing the procedure cache, and the session cache:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
GO
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ( 'ALL')
GO
```

and I cleared everything, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out there are a couple of ways of quickly shrinking or emptying TempDB files and drop them.
The first way.

1. Change locations and sizes for all `TempDB` data and log files in `system catalogs` and restart SQL instance.

   - `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE(NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = '<file_location>', SIZE = <size>);`
   - `ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE(NAME = templog, FILENAME = '<file_location>', SIZE = <size>);`
2. Restart SQL Server instance, drop old TempDB files

And one more way.

1. Start SQL Server with [minimal configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-with-minimal-configuration?view=sql-server-2017) - using -f parameter and connect via sqlcmd
2. Delete unneeded files:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE tempdb REMOVE FILE [<LogicalFileName>]
   ```

Comment: +2 on the first method, -1 on the second method :-)

Answer (score 1):

General algorithm:

1. Determine the logical file names of the tempdb database and their current location on the disk:

   SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation
   FROM sys.master_files
   WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');
2. Change the location of each file by using ALTER DATABASE:

   USE master;
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE tempdb
   MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'E:\SQLData\tempdb.mdf');
   GO
   ALTER DATABASE tempdb
   MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'F:\SQLLog\templog.ldf');
   GO
3. Stop and restart the instance of SQL Server
4. Verify the file change:

   SELECT name, physical_name AS CurrentLocation, state_desc
   FROM sys.master_files
   WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');
5. Delete the tempdb.mdf and templog.ldf files from the original location

For more information, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017).